# Cannot parse the data from CSV file if there is an enter key pressed between two words in same cell

Tags: c#, csv

I am trying to parse the csv file using the following code

```
string[] EachColumnData = null;
EachColumnData  = line.Replace("\",\"", "|").Replace(",,", "||").Replace("\"", "").Split('|');
```

But  it doesnot work,if there is an enter key pressed in between two words of a column value, it would be splitted as new row .
I have attached my sample csv format herewith.  How can I fix my code to accept the data as a single record even if there is space or enter inside a column value.[image]

Comment: Be sure to reject files that are not properly formatted as a .csv file.

Comment: Use a dedicated csv parser. NuGet has several, and some of them can handle things like newlines in fields.